# Run bash script from php as another user

Tags: php, linux, bash, ubuntu, permissions

I would like to run a bash script without opening a terminal in my Ubuntu system. Some other users will have to daily check and run that process. So I thought I could build a simple php website that could run the script. After some reading here at Stack Overflow and googleing  I thought shell_exec could do the trick. But as I don't want to give permissions in some directories to www-data I want to run the scripts as the owner, user meteo.

This is my php:

```
$autput = shell_exec('date +%d/%m/%Y-%H:%m');
echo "<pre>Hora de inicio: $autput</pre>";

$output = shell_exec('/home/meteo/RAMS/SCRIPTS/RAMS_operatiu.bash');
echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";
```

The content of sudoers file, `sudo visudo`

```
meteo   ALL = NOPASSWD: /home/meteo/RAMS/SCRIPTS/RAMS_operatiu.bash
www-data   ALL = NOPASSWD: /home/meteo/RAMS/SCRIPTS/RAMS_operatiu.bash
```

This way, www-data user runs my script (RAMS_operatiu.bash) but as this script runs an mpich job it has to check mpd.conf then the script crashes as there is not such file for www-data. It actually exists for meteo. So I would like to run as meteo better than www-data. I tried to use

```
$output = shell_exec('sudo -u meteo /home/meteo/www/RAMS/inicio_RAMS.sh');
```

but can't find the point to tell the php script to run as meteo, not www-data. Is this possible? Probably I am missing something.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If you need to run it periodically / daily, wouldn't it be easier to set up a cron-job for that user that runs the script automatically?

Comment: you can probably run php script "under another user id" using this function http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-setuid.php

Comment: Hi @jeroen and yes. I am also trying to daily schedule to run a cron-job. But, this is another question, my script runs from the terminal but not from cron (I have an open question at mpich-discuss mailing list). I thought I could try the php to give the other users the option to run the script. I can connect via ssh and run the script but don't want other users to do. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @petrbel Shoud I add `posix_setuid(1000);` before shell_exec()

Comment: @petrbel Have tried but still runs as www-data. Could you give an example of such function `posix_setuid`. Thanks.

Comment: @pacomet Please don't forget that user "www-data" must be allowed to change UID. That may be your problem. Some examples can be found at link I posted above :)

Comment: @petrbel Ok, I've seen the examples. As a newbie php user they seem complicated. I will further investigate your suggestion as it looks promising. Thanks.

Comment: @pacomet well, keep in mind that this is more unix issue (I guess that windows have some implementation as well) that php one - this is about right system user privilliges

Comment: Connected question on Ask Ubuntu [link](http://askubuntu.com/q/432767/25305)